# C++ Multiple Include Annoyances

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, linker, include

So I'm writing a program which has gotten large enough now that it has several separate source files, and as a result, several separate header files. I keep constantly running into multiple include issues.

The problem is that I compile all of the individual files before I link them. So, A.cpp and B.cpp both include Z.h, because both A.cpp and B.cpp use function declarations and the such which exist inside of Z.h . This is all fine during the compile stage, because everything is in order, but when I go to link A.o and B.o together, the compiler (linker) throws multiple definition errors, because it's included the function definitions from Z.h while it was compiling each of the .o files, and so they exist in both .o files. This can normally be avoided by using include guards, but in this case, they won't work, since each .cpp file is compiled separately, the compiler "forgets" the state of defined preprocessor variables.

So my question is, how is this solved in the real world? I've had a good dig around and have come up dry, but I'm certain that this must have been solved before.

Thanks!

Comment: Your headers may miss some `extern` or `inline`

Comment: A good reading (google search term) is One Definition Rule and violations of thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, A.cpp and B.cpp both include Z.h, because both A.cpp and B.cpp use
>   function declarations and the such which exist inside of Z.h

This cannot be technically correct, or at least it's an incomplete description. `Z.h` most likely does not only contain function **declarations** but also function **definitions**.

Function declaration:

```
void f();
```

Function definition:

```
void f() { std::cout << "doing something\n"; }
```

> So my question is, how is this solved in the real world?

You solve this problem by keeping the declarations in `Z.h` and moving the definitions into yet another to-be-created `Z.cpp` file.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I see now, the function definition was kind of difficult to see, because it was in the form of:

PFNGLUSEPROGRAMPROC glUseProgram;

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say exactly what problem you're running into without code, but you are probably defining functions or variables in your headers.  That's not what headers are for unless the functions are `inline` or templates.  Including a header is like copy/pasting all the code in it into your cpp file.  If you have the same variable in every cpp file, and it's not static or in an anonymous namespace, you'll have multiple definitions when you try to link and the linker will puke.